# Command to use with scratch docker container

Tags: mysql, bash, docker

I'm trying to start a docker container for mysql.  The image for the container was built from scratch for a training I attended and I need to figure out how to configure it to run a command that will start the container.

The /bin/bash and /bin/sh commands don't work.  When I docker inspect the container the CMD section doesn't contain anything.  I've tried running CMD['/bin/bash'] or CMD['/bin/sh'] at the end of my docker container run command and that populates the CMD field but the container still won't run.

There are a number of other microservice containers I'm having the same problem with.  This is the first one I need to solve however.

This is the command I'm running:

```
docker run -d -v infytel-mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql --network=infytel-docker-networkMS --name=infytel-mysql-con2 -e MYSQL_PASSWORD_ROOT=root infytel-mysql-img:v1 /bin/bash
```

This is my error:

```
oci runtime error: container_linux.go:235: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory
```

[EDIT] Running docker logs gives the error shown above.

Running without the /bin/sh command states `error response from daemon: No command specified`

Comment: If its build correctly the entrypoint will start the service. What does it do if bash/sh isn't specified? What does `docker logs infytel-mysql-con2` show? If you are having trouble, include how the container was created and the logs from above in your question.

Comment: Is it literally `FROM scratch`?  That won't include any sort of shell in it.  Can you include the Dockerfile in the question?  Why do you need to override the command at the `docker run` line?

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't think I have access to the Dockerfile.  The images aren't from Docker Hub or a repo.  They were included with a virtual hard disk we were given for the training we went through.  When I say from scratch I mean that the docker image was likely created from a fresh install of mysql, not built from another mysql container.  I don't know why.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Have you tried to put `/bin/sh` at the end of your command ?

Comment: @Philippe Yes, I've put both /bin/sh and /bin/bash at the end.